# Adding a tuple to a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know, this is easy...

I have the following tuple:

```
((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

I need to add (7,8) to this so the result:

```
((7,8), (1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, you will need to create a new tuple.

```
mytuple = ((7,8),) + mytuple
```

`((7,8),)` is a tuple which contains exactly one tuple.
The additional comma is needed to distinguish a tuple with one element from an expression.

Demo:

```
>>> a = (3)
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> a = (3,)
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

For `((7,8),)`:

```
>>> a = ((7,8))
>>> a
(7, 8)
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(a[0])
<class 'int'>
>>> a = ((7,8),)
>>> a
((7, 8),)
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(a[0])
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also to use append() method :

```
yourTuple.append(valueToAppend)
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tuple_append.htm

Comment: Umm... No. That tutorial is shit. Python tuples are immutable, so no append, and the result they "get" (try the "try it" button...) is `Updated Tuple :  [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 2009]` – a list.